# Fetch Ring Group and Personal calls from call log

Tags: postgresql, fusionpbx

I am trying to customize FusionPBX. In my dashboard, I want to list the incoming, placed and missed calls. I want to show this in two columns, one for 'Personal' Calls and the other for 'Ring Group' calls. I can't find any relation between `xml_cdr` and `ring_groups` table. How do I fetch the 'Ring Group' and 'Personal' calls from the `xml_cdr` table?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote FusionPBX and I don't have a specific way to do what you are asking except call detail records will show ring_group_uuid when the call comes from a ring group. This may help accomplish what you need.